# How can I select only external edges in this mesh?

Tags: mesh, edges

I want select only external edges in this mesh, because i want to extrude them to remove empty areas.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select one of the candidate edges in edge select mode. Then Select similar -> Amount of Faces Around en edge.

[image]